# Author information column wise

Tags: authblk

I am using **authblk** package and I want to achieve following output using this package. 
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need the `authblk` package to achieve the desired look.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Author Practice}
\author{%
\begin{tabular}{c} Author 1 \\ University \\ Email-id \end{tabular} \and
\begin{tabular}{c} Author 2 \\ University \\ Email-id \end{tabular} \and
\begin{tabular}{c} Author 3 \\ University \\ Email-id \end{tabular} \and
\begin{tabular}{c} Author 4 \\ University \\ Email-id \end{tabular} }
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

---

Here's a different look, prompted by the OP's (now-deleted) comments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Author Practice}
\author{%
\begin{tabular}{c} Author 1 \\ University1 \\ Mail1 \\ \\
Author 3 \\ University3 \\ Mail3 \end{tabular} \and
\begin{tabular}{c} Author 2 \\ University2 \\ Mail2 \\ \\
Author 4 \\ University4 \\ Mail4\\
\end{tabular} }
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: After adding data alignment got distorted. Each author info is coming in a separate row.I wanted to come in blocks like                                         author1          author2                                      university       university                                    mail             mail

Comment: @taheralirangwala - May I suggest you edit your original query to provide more and specific information as to what is to be shown? As you can tell, I patterned my answer after your original query; if the original query is not what you're really trying to get typeset, please do show some of the real information.

Comment: I have added image in answer as how I want author format.

Comment: @taheralirangwala - I've posted an addendum to my answer; hopefully, the new code satisfies your needs.